# POST (url) net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

Tags: javascript

I am getting the below below when i try to the url
https://www.cshippers.com/orderManagement/OrderManagementReportAction.action?actionCommand=submit&menuRef=REP_APP005_0001MT

The error:
POST (url) net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

[image]

The JavaScript Function:

```
$.ajax({
    url:targetUrl, //supposed to be the url as mentioned in question
    data: formData.serialize(),
    cache: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (dataofconfirm) {
        openPage( url.substring(0, url.indexOf(".",2)) + ".action?menuRef="+menuRef );
        /*hideLoader();*/
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        hideLoader();
        console.log( thrownError );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Usually, there are two problems:

1. Related to adblocker and you need to turn it off
2. You need to add an extra segment at the end of your URL

For example "https://--your api--/***movie.json***". You need to add the target node in your database, here it is movie, at the end of the URL.

Firebase needs this ***.json*** at the end of the URL you are sending requests to, otherwise your request will fail.
If you are using Firebase, it could solve your problem.

You can test your API with one of the online open API testing.